# How can I detect that my a website/PWA has been loaded into the foreground?

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

I have a Progressive Web App for Ipad written in React, and I'd like to detect when a user reloads the app after switching to another. Is there a browser event or serrvice worker event I can subscribe to for when the app is reloaded?

Along a similar thread, is there a way to tell that a progressive web app has been force closed and reopened?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could make use of a [`visibilitychange` event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilitychange_event) to detect when a web app that was previously in the background is now in the foreground:

```
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function() {
  if (document.visibilityState === 'visible') {
    // Your code here...
  }
});
```

There's more information about the Page Lifecycle APIs in [this post](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/07/page-lifecycle-api), but you should note that not all of the states available in the API are exposed in Safari. The post lists [some caveats](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/07/page-lifecycle-api#managing-cross-browsers-differences) to pay attention to when writing code that works across multiple browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [GoogleChromeLabs/page-lifecycle](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/page-lifecycle) library for a cross-browser method of subscribing to page lifecycle events.

```js
import lifecycle from 'page-lifecycle'

lifecycle.addEventListener('statechange', ({ oldState, newState }) => {
  console.log(`${oldState} -> ${newState}`)
})
```

In my testing, iOS PWA is limited in which events fire:

- **Switch away**: active → passive, passive → hidden
- **Switch to**: hidden → passive, passive → active
- **Activate app switcher and back**: no change

I did not find any way to detect that the app was force closed and reopened.

Comment: For anyone reading this answer, page-lifecycle library is not very stable and is not maintained well. I came across some crashes on production. I would rather suggest using react-page-visibility library.

Comment: @jarora could you be more explicit about the crashes that you encountered in production?

Comment: I can't seem to remember now. But as I have suggested in my comment above, you may use the react-page-visibility library instead.